# d3 selection.remove() doesn't remove

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I need to remove my x axis. Here's my [minimal nonworking example](http://jsfiddle.net/6FPNW/)

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="chart" ng-switch="col.type">
    <svg width="150" height="20">
        <g class="main" transform="translate(5,5)"> ... </g>
        <g class="x axis" transform="translate(5,5)"> ... </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

My JavaScript (using D3) is like this:

```
svg.selectAll(".x.axis").remove();
```

I'm pretty sure that the `svg` variable is correctly selected because it was used in my previous code without problem.

Here are a couple of things I've tried:

```
svg.selectAll("g.x.axis").remove();

svg.selectAll(".x.axis").data([]).exit().remove();

svg.selectAll("g.x.axis").data([]).exit().remove();

svg.selectAll(".x").data([]).exit().remove();

svg.selectAll(".x").remove();
```

But none of them remove the x axis for me :(

Debugging output:

```
console.log("SVG data: " + svg );
// output: SVG data: [object SVGGElement] 

console.log("x axis: " + svg.selectAll("g.x.axis") );
// output: x axis:
```

Comment: it seems to be working check this out http://jsbin.com/AfIhijO/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @SaravanaKumar yeah it's working in the demo, but not in my code... weird

Comment: Can you share more info about you code? How you initializing svg object. Also try debugging with console.logging the svg object and svg.selectAll("g.x.axis").

Comment: thanks! I've put my minimal not-working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6FPNW/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/7ZMaF/)**

```
 var svg = d3.select(".chart").select("svg");
    svg.selectAll(".x.axis").remove();
```

Comment: thanks! it's working in the demo but not in my code... could I have missed something?

Comment: try to add id then select that x..  svg.selectAll("#x").remove(); http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/Hz9Vx/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/uqGK5/ ..try to add id then select that x.. svg.select("#x").remove();

Comment: thanks! I've put my minimal non-working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6FPNW/)

Comment: chart is not defined in Your code ,that's why var svg is not working

Answer (score 1):

You have missed quotes for class name in chart. Check this out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6FPNW/2)

```
var svg = d3.select(".chart").select("svg");
svg.selectAll(".x.axis").remove();
```